# How to check (or even set) collation in mdb (ms access) file

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access, collation

I succesfully migrated Access DB to MySQL DB. All seems to be fine but i need more specific behaviour of MySQL DB.
I need exactly the same sorting of query result as in Access DB after choose option **"sort A to Z"**.
I use this result in Java application.

MySQL table is UTF-8 and collation is set utf8_general_ci.
Example query is:

```
"SELECT encode, language FROM suffixes ORDER BY encode COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"
```

It returns similar result but there are unacceptable differences in sorting.

Access sorts result like this:

```
001_01._02.1_02.2.1_02.4_05.e.3.1_07.2.2_15.5.d_20.3.2.1_31.2.2_33.3.4_001
001_01._02.1_02.4.1_06.4.1_06.4.2_07.2.1.1_07.2.2_10.1_11.1.3_20.3.2.1_20.3.7_20.6.8_001
```

Java sorts result like this:

```
001_01._02.1_02.2.1_02.4_05.e.3.1_07.2.2_15.5.d_20.3.2.1_31.2.2_33.3.4_001                                                              
001_01._02.1_02.4_06.1_06.2.4.1.2_06.2.4.1.3_06.3.1_07.2.1.1_07.2.2.1_11.2.2_15.2.1.a.1_15.5.a_20.3.2.2.1.a_20.7.1.5_20.8_33.4.5.3_001
```

Additionaly I don't know how to check charset and collation in Access.

Can anybody give me a hint what i should do to obtain proper results?

Comment: Google quickly tells you how to get/set the [default value for new databases](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/133381/EN-US) but how to retrieve the actual value for an existing DB seems to be an industrial secret...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.
I used Collator class for proper sorting.

FYI it looks like this (this is sorting of ArrayList):

```
public class AccessSorter
{ 
final static String letters = "< a, A < b, B < c, C < d, D < e, E < f, F < g, G < h, H < i, I < j, J < k, K < l, L < m, M < n, N < o, O < p, P < q, Q < r, R < s, S < t, T < u, U < v, V < w, W < x, X < y, Y < z, Z";
final static String digits = "< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9";
final static String special = "< '.' < '_'";
private RuleBasedCollator accessCollator;


AccessSorter()
{
    try
    {
        accessCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(special + digits + letters);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


SomeComparator getSomeComparator()
{
    return new SomeComparator();
}

class SomeComparator implements Comparator<String[]>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] s1, String[] s2)
    {
       return accessCollator.compare(s1[1], s2[1]);
    }
}
```

}

example of usage:

```
Collections.sort(someCollectionOfStringArray, new AccessSorter().getSomeComparator()
```

And now you don't need to worry about collations of access or mySQL. You set rules by yourselve. Of course it takes some time to sort such array.
Remember, if you need to sort big arrays more than once, consider using of getCollatorKey() to increase efficiency.
Also remember if you need to add to collator semicolons, periods, quotation marks put them into ' '.
I hope it will help you somehow.
Regards.