# UCanAccess in Java returning wrong order with ORDER BY clause in column with special characters

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, ucanaccess

Using the Microsoft Access Database (2007-2013) with a .mdb file, I created a simple `test_table` table with only one text column `"name"` and inserted the following test values:

```
óbito,
fanatico,
orbita,
fanático,
fanta,
órbita,
fantástico,
obito,
obituario,
orbitando
```

When I execute the query `SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY name` using MS Access query design, the following ordered result is returned:

```
fanatico,
fanático,
fanta,
fantástico,
obito,
óbito,
obituario,
orbita,
órbita,
orbitando
```

This order is totally correct and expected.

Now, I need to retrieve and use these values in my Java software. In order to do this, I am using the [UCanAccess JDBC driver](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) on version `5.0.0` to connect to the database. The connection itself is successfully being opened, but, when I execute the **same** query above, it returns the following:

```
fanatico
fanta
fantástico
fanático
obito
obituario
orbita
orbitando
óbito
órbita
```

And this is NOT the correct order (for instance, `óbito` should come immediately after `obito`). The desired order should consider accented words as if they were the same as the equivalent unnacented word.
It doesn't matter if `óbito` comes before or after `obito`, but they **must be together**.
I tried using `COLLATE`, tried changing the charset, etc, but nothing worked. Has anyone gone through something similar and could you help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The driver is sorting by their binary representation and/or the individual ASCII characters. Both provide the sort order you provided at the bottom. This is entirely a problem created by the driver, and "fixes" are going to be limited.

There is a workaround posted in the JDBC driver changelog, under the 2.0.9.3 Release notes: `WORKAROUND suggested: if you want the same behaviour of Access: select * from table2 order by orderJet( COLUMN1).`

If that doesn't work, then you either need to
a) subvert the driver's sorting by creating/maintaining a SORTORDER column in the original database that holds the same word with all accented characters stripped, or b) find a way to change the sort *after* it arrives from the driver. Neither of these are preferable, so I hope the workaround provided by the developer is sufficient.

Comment: With your answer, the new query generated was `select * from test_table order by orderJet(name)`, but it's still returning the same undesired order.... The "a)" solution is impossible because I can't modify the database, but only read from it. The "b)" isn't impossible but it is not recommended, as I'm usually dealing with millions of rows.

Comment: @GuilhermeBarboza You can use a `SELECT` with no `ORDER BY` clause and do the sort yourself (which moves the sorting task from the driver to your code).

Answer (score 1):

Java by default do not perform locale-sensitive String comparison.
In your example I tried following ran program as below for natural sorting

```
 List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"óbito",
            "fanatico",
            "orbita",
            "fanático",
            "fanta",
            "órbita",
            "fantástico",
            "obito",
            "obituario",
            "orbitando"});
    
    Collections.sort(strings);
    System.out.println("Output = " + strings);
```

the output is

```
Output = [fanatico, fanta, fantástico, fanático, obito, obituario, orbita, orbitando, óbito, órbita]
```

Now jut by replacing sort by below line

```
Collections.sort(strings, Collator.getInstance(Locale.US));
```

I am getting output which you are expecting

```
Output = [fanatico, fanático, fanta, fantástico, obito, óbito, obituario, orbita, órbita, orbitando]
```

Giving you example above to understand the difference when you use string comparison using  locale-sensitive. There are ways you can handle this from your code or from db configuration.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487556/how-to-check-or-even-set-collation-in-mdb-ms-access-file) for example

Comment: I can't use your solution because I can't simultaneously load all the data from the MS Access database, as I'm dealing with millions of rows. The memory wouldn't be able to handle all the information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enforcing a CharSet?

Have a look here [CharSet for MS Access '97 DB using UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714917/charset-for-ms-access-97-db-using-ucanaccess)

```
class DatabaseOpener : JackcessOpenerInterface {
  override fun open(fl: File, pwd: String?): Database {
    return DatabaseBuilder.open(fl).apply {
      this.charset = charset("Cp1252")
    }
  }
}

// URL
"jdbc:ucanaccess://<path-to-mdb-file>;memory=false;jackcessOpener=${DatabaseOpener::class.qualifiedName!!}"
```

When using plain JDBC connection you could try adding a connection parameter:

```
private static java.sql.ResultSet executeDataTable(String sql) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    String conStr = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dataDir + "ABC.mdb";
    Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
    props.put("charSet", "Cp1252");
    java.sql.Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(conStr, props);

    java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    return stmt.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

You need to check what your charset might be. So potentially replace 'Cp1252'.

Comment: So what should be the charset? I've tried `Cp1252`, `ISO-8859-1`, `UTF-8`, `utf8`, `utf8mb4`,  and `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` but nothing worked so far. No exceptions were thrown though.